# Is a continuum of mixtures of stable distributions (e.g. normals) stable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Take some random variable $X$ and indices $i \in [0,1]$.  Let $X$ be a stable distribution, (i.e. for any copies $i,i'$, $a,b>0$, $a X_i + b X_{i'} \sim c X + d$ for some $c$ and $d$).  This obviously generalizes for any finite mixture.

My question is whether a *continuum* of mixtures is stable?
i.e.
Let $a(i)>0$ be some weighting such that $\int_{0}^{1}a(i)d i < \infty$ then for some $c$, $d$ is,

$$
\int_0^1 a(i)X_i d i \sim c X + d?
$$

(I suspect that the answer is not true in general, but would like a reference or proof, at least for Normal distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be a zero-mean, unit-variance normal (with characteristic function $\phi_X(t) = e^{-t^2/2}$). Define
$$S_n =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a(k/n) X_{k/n},$$ and $T_n = S_n/n$.
The characteristic function of $S_n$ is
$$\phi_{S_n}(t) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi_X(a(k/n)\cdot t) =\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a(k/n)^2\right)$$
(since $S_n$ is just a normal with mean 0 and variance $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a(k/n)^2$), and the characteristic function of $T_n$ is
$$
\phi_{T_n}(t) = \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2} \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a(k/n)^2}{n^2}\right)
$$
If we let then $\int_0^1 a(i)X_i di$ be the Riemann integral $\lim_{n\to\infty} T_n$, it looks like if $a(i)$ is square-integrable, for any $t$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_{T_n}(t) = 1$, so the integral is the degenerate zero distribution; this sort of makes sense since the integral is averaging an infinite number of normal RVs.

If we just take un-skewed stable distributions with characteristic function $\phi_X(t) = e^{-|t|^\alpha}$, the corresponding $T_n$ has CF
$$
  \phi_{T_n}(t) = \exp\left(-|t|^\alpha \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |a(k/n)|^\alpha}{n^\alpha}\right),
$$
which appears to converge as $n\to\infty$ only if $\alpha = 1$ to a Cauchy RV with a scale parameter $\int_0^1 |a(i)| di$; it converges to 0 if $\alpha > 1$ and diverges if $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much, that looks pretty solid.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the stability fail, in this same sense, for a countably infinite number of RVs as well?